# FlameRobin on-disk structure support

Tags: firebird, firebird2.1, flamerobin

I use Firebird 2.1 on Windows 7 Pro.

I try to connect database with Flamerobin 0.9.2. It has worked before, but now I get the following error message from every database I try to connect to.

```
IBPP::SQLException
Context: Database::Connect
Message: isc_attach_database_failed

SQL Message: -820
wrong or obsolete version
Engine Code:335544379
Engine Message:
unsupported on-disk structure for file 
E:\tietokannat\oma.fdb; found 32779.15, support @4?.@5?
```

I have tried re-installed FlameRobin. I checked ODS version by gstat and database is 11.1. I can connect to database by Delphi 10.2.

Most I don't understand "support @4?.@5?" Before if I had tried to connect not supported ODS version, FlameRobin has informed properly like "support 11.1" Has something to do with the InterBase

Comment: The error has nothing to do with FlameRobin. You are trying to use InterBase to connect to a Firebird database (or vice versa). They aren't compatible. And the confusing error message is because you are using Firebird's fbclient and firebird.msg error messages, while receiving the error from InterBase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do I get an unsupported on-disk structure error in FlameRobin?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643098/why-do-i-get-an-unsupported-on-disk-structure-error-in-flamerobin)

Comment: @MarkRotteveel I haven't Interbase running, only Firebird. I have Interbase XE3 files in workstation. Is it possible that some DLL confuse

Comment: The error is clear, that 32779 in the error message means it is a Firebird ODS 11.x database (to avoid compatibility issues with InterBase, the Firebird ODS is masked), the 15 is the ODS expected by InterBase. If you had used an InterBase gds32.dll and its message file, the error would probably have rendered as "Wrong ODS version, expected 15, encountered 32779".  I don't use InterBase myself, so I can't offer any help troubleshooting that.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel Now I found that there was Interbase service running on machine. When I disabled it, then everything is ok. Thanks! What is correct way to show, how this case is solved? And solution was stop Interbase service.

Comment: Consider posting your own answer and accepting that after the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

I found that Interbase service was running on the machine. Flamerobin use that service, delphi 10.2 use Firebird. After stopping Interbase service Flamerobin started to work.

Comment: If you want them running side-by-side, you could configure one or the other to run on a different port (setting `RemoteServicePort` in `firebird.conf`).