# How to define login and password in Firebird based application?

Tags: firebird, firebird2.5

I know, this is not a strictly programming error, because I did not wrote this program, but I have a Streamsoft Pro installed on one PC and when I copied all program data to second machine I got error:

```
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements.
unsupported on-disk structure for file c:\STREAM soft\STREAM soft SQL\Baza\SYSTEMST.FB; found 11.2, support 11.1
```

Found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643098/why-do-i-get-an-unsupported-on-disk-structure-error-in-flamerobin) tat it is Firebird version related error so I updated it to 2.5.8 and now I get other error:

```
DMSystem.SystemDatabase:
Unsuccessful execution caused by a system error that precludes successful execution of subsequent statements.
Your username and password are not defined. Ask your database administrator to set up a Firebird login.
```

And my question is:
How to set up those?

Answer (score 2):

Firebird has all the users/passwords saved in so-called "security database" that is one per installed Firebird instance.

It is may be more complex/flexible with Firebird 3 or 4, but that is not your case.

There can be several Firebird 1.x or 2.x instances running on a computer, each would have it's own "security database". But usually there is only one instance of Firebird on a computer, if at all, so in most cases you may think there is one "security database" keeping Firebird users and password on a computer.

> I got error about Firebird version
>    I updated it to 2.5.8

You do not spell it out explicitly, so I may only guess what you actually did.

But if I can read the stars then it was like this:

1. You installed some wrong version of Firebird. Either 2.0.x or 2.1.x or maybe even 3.0.x - but the one SteamSoft could not work with.
2. There is high chance, but no warrant, that during installation SteamSoft found that wrong Firebird version and created the required users/logins into that wrong Firebird instance's "security database".
3. When you removed that wrong Firebird installation (you DID uninstall it, didn't you??? 'cause having several FB instances on one computer is possible but requires special arrangements and you did not report you did them) - the "security database" of it was orphaned. *No, you can not just find it and throw at Firebird 2.5 - different FB versions have different incompatible formats of it.*
4. When you installed fresh FB 2.5.8 - it had the usual clean "security database" only having `SYSDBA` user and none of SteamSoft-specific users.
5. When you run SteamSoft against this clean "security database" of FB 2.5 - it tries to login with non-existent users and fails.

If this reading crystal ball was correct, then the most simple approach would be then to

1. Uninstall SteamSoft.
2. Verify that Firebird 2.5.8. was not uninstalled together with SS, nor de-activated. For example, if you reboot your computer and then open Windows Services - there should still be "Firebird Server Default Instance" service in "running" state.
3. Install SteamSoft. Hopefully it would find the running FB 2.5.8 and would automatically create all the required custom users into it.

Alternatively you may consult SteamSoft documentation or their support.

- http://www.streamsoft.eu/about-us/#contact
- http://firebirdsql.org/en/case-studies-catalog/streamsoft-38114

There is a fair chance you can just create the missing users yourself, using either SteamSoft-provided diagnostic utilities, or just built-in Firebird commands (if you would obtain the required list of users and passwords - but SteamSoft might be unwilling to spell them out). Creating the users would be much faster then re-installing SteamSoft, however learning how and what to create might be longer for non-experienced user.

If you can, you may install Firebird on the new computer of exactly the same version as it was on the first computer, them (while having Firebird Server services temporarily stopped on both) copy the `security database` from old computer to new one. It contains users and passwords.

Alternatively, after you obtain the list of required usernames and passwords, you may manually create them in Firebird on the new computer

- using command-line GSEC utility in Firebird's folder: https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/reference_manuals/user_manuals/html/gsec.html
- issuing SQL commands in any FB-compatible SQL utility, such as iSQL command-line utility in Firebird's folder or free FlameRobin IDE, or any other. https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd25-new-in-25-security.html.

P.S. There is still one another case possible. Users and passwords are a feature of "standalone" Firebird server (running as a special program on its own).

Maybe SteamSoft was designed to work with "Firebird Embedded", that is with a library that is not running on its own, but gets embedded into SteamSoft program itself. Firebird Embedded does not have any users and passwords at all. If such would turn out the case, then SteamSoft was not providing non-existing usernames and passwords, but none at all. And then it might turn out SteamSoft being incompatible with non-Embedded versions of Firebird. But this you can only check with SteamSoft documentation or helpdesk.

Comment: My Firebird error was exactly as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643098/why-do-i-get-an-unsupported-on-disk-structure-error-in-flamerobin) so yes, I uninstalled firebird 2.1 and installed 2.5.8. I haven't got any installator for StreamSoft to use on my second PC, so I just copied all data connected to StreamSoft application from first PC and hoped it will work. I had to change some settings to match new paths, but that was easy. Only thing that still occurs is the login/pass error.

Comment: if you install exactly the same version of Firebird onto the second computer as you have in the first - you would be able to copy security database from one PC to another (stopping FB services on both before copying and restarting them after). That would copy users/passwords, BUT it would copy none of the other configurations, like maybe UDFs or special paths for External Tables. High chances, StreamSoft does NOT use them, but maybe it does. It would be better to get the installation package and specific documentation WHAT exactly does their program need from Firebird instance. Contact them.

Comment: I wonder how did you copied the database file. Copying it while FB service is running can potentially damage the data. Which would not be easy to spot... Also, why would you even do it? Won't it be better not to copy the database, but to setup the programs on both computers to work with the same database on the first computer over the network?

Comment: I cannot install StreamSoft again, because I don't have CD from 2012 or newer. And on their site it says that with win10 (second PC) you need 2012 CD or newer.

Comment: About how I copied everything. I did stop everything (StreamSoft related as their site said) and then copied everything and copied base has not got any differences from original one.

Comment: It does not matter when CD was made. What matters is what program version is written on it. If that program works on Win10 (even unofficially) the nit does. If not - then not. So if I were in your shoes, then first I would try to install by official installer, maybe in "compatibility mode". Only if official installer would not work, then maybe I would copy the installed program, and then hope that maybe what did not work was installer and all other parts of program do work (but maybe they do not work too). Did you stopped Firebird service or not? I do not read polish and do not know what

Comment: particular part of site you read. If you did not - then it is possible part of data was in the memory not in file. Then you copied only the in-file part not in-memory part. Granted, it happens when the program is running and actively exchanging data. So, if you like rebooted the computer before copying - it would flush data into file, so would just stopping FB service. Just a safe practice and good habit.

Comment: First time I did not stop FB service before copying, but now I did. I will see if it works now.

Comment: Nothing worked. I guess I will shut both PCs down. And contact to StreamSoft tommorow and figure out what to do with them.

Comment: why do you even need a separate database @SkillGG ? do computers see one another in the network? just make StreamSoft on BOTH computers connect with Firebird server-and-database on the FIRST computer !

Comment: If you still want separate databases and FB servers, then you have to recreate the required users and passwords. One way is to install exactly the same FB version on new computer as FB was on the first computer and then copy the `security database` from 1st to 2nd (while both FB services down). Another - to anyhow learn required usernames and FB passwords and create them on new compute using FB's GSEC command-line tool  or iSQL (or any FB-aware SQL IDE)

Comment: My first PC (with Vista) was very slow, so i bought another one with Win10. Way faster one. I had it installed as a one-pc setup on my previous pc, so there was no network between them. I gave both PCs (laptops) to streamsoft and told them that I want to move everything from pc1 to pc2. They said ok, and did everything as I wanted.

Comment: sometimes it makes sense just to copy the whole old computer into any Virtual machine and have it within the new one

Comment: That would be a nice solution :P

Comment: Then try it, if you new computer has enough HDD and RAM then it can work.
I use sysinternals.com ustility to copy oldcomputer into VHD (Microsoft generation 1 Virtual HD, and NOT gen.2 VHDX) then run it through Oracle VirtualBox

Answer (score 0):

The first error means that your database was of a newer version than the Firebird install. It is usually better to use backup and restore to move databases between systems. Given you already solved that error, I will only point to [Why do I get an unsupported on-disk structure error when opening a Firebird database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43643098/why-do-i-get-an-unsupported-on-disk-structure-error-in-flamerobin) for more details.

As to the second error, it means that login failed. Either the user does not exist, or the wrong password was used. A default Firebird installation only comes with a single user: `SYSDBA` (depending on the OS and installer either with password `masterkey` or a randomly generated password).

Your application probably needs a specific user, and given Firebird stores the users in a separate security database, that user does not exist. Find out what the username should be of that user and create it.

You can create users in Firebird 2.5 in two ways:

1. Using [SQL user management statements](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/refdocs/fblangref25/firebird-25-language-reference.html#fblangref25-security-auth-manage-users):

   ```sql
   create user <username> password <password>;
   commit;
   ```

This requires SYSDBA access (or a user with administrator privileges in the security database).

2. Using the command line tool [gsec](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/html/en/firebirddocs/gsec/firebird-gsec.html) (deprecated since Firebird 3 in favor of SQL user management statements)

   ```
   gsec -user sysdba -password <sysdba-password>
   add <username> -pw <password>
   ```